# Batch rename images to folder name + sequential number

Tags: linux, bash

I want to rename files in a directory with subdirectories to parent it's directory name + sequential numbers.

For example:

```
hello-images/
    ├── first-black
    │   ├── full_b200056_m.png
    │   ├── full_b200056_x_DSC01973.JPG
    │   ├── full_b200056_x_DSC01978.JPG
    │   ├── full_b200056_x_DSC01988.JPG
    │   ├── full_b200056_x_DSC01994.JPG
    │   ├── full_b200056_x_DSC02003.JPG
    ├── second-atlas
    │   ├── full_b200035_m1.png
    │   ├── full_b200035_x_3926.JPG
    │   ├── full_b200035_x_3928.JPG
    │   ├── full_b200035_x_3931.JPG
    │   ├── full_b200035_x_3944.JPG
```

Desidered result:

```
hello-images/
├── first-black
│   ├── first-black_1.png
│   ├── first-black_2.JPG
│   ├── first-black_3.JPG
│   ├── first-black_4.JPG
│   ├── first-black_5.JPG
│   ├── first-black_6.JPG
├── second-atlas
│   ├── second-atlas_1.png
│   ├── second-atlas_2.JPG
│   ├── second-atlas_3.JPG
│   ├── second-atlas_4.JPG
│   ├── second-atlas_5.JPG
```

Comment: Why are the images under `first-black` renamed as `1,3,4,5,6,7` why not `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `hello-images` directory, do:

```
for d in */; do i=1; for f in "$d"/*.*; do echo mv -- "$f" "$d${d%/}_${i}.${f##*.}"; ((i++)); done; done
```

This is dry-run, it will show the `mv` commands to be run. If satisfied with the changes to be made, remove `echo` for actual action:

```
for d in */; do i=1; for f in "$d"/*.*; do mv -- "$f" "$d${d%/}_${i}.${f##*.}"; ((i++)); done; done
```

Expanded form:

```
for d in */; do 
    i=1
    for f in "$d"/*.*; do 
        mv -- "$f" "$d${d%/}_${i}.${f##*.}"
        ((i++))
    done
done
```

Comment: Hi, I just edited your code, It was missing underscore and .jpg extension from the final filename. One little problem with the code: renamed files are moved into root hello-images/ directory.

Comment: @Adrian Don't hardcode anything, check now.